# Removing a space

Tags: php

I have a variable

```
$abc='akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn';
```

Another variable

```
$url =  'http://alpha.com/zidd/id/'.$abc;
```

Which is giving me

```
http://alpha.com/zidd/id/ akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn
```

A space is being introduced between `id/` and `akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn` which I do not want.

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: You probably have an extra space in one of your strings (use `trim` to remove it).

Comment: `$abc=akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn` is not valid PHP (*fixed now*). Assuming you add the quotes correctly, it should work perfectly: http://codepad.org/kHtVNkk1

Comment: is it `$abc=akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn` or is it `$abc="akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn";` your example would throw error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you should put quotes around your string literal

```
$abc = 'akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn';
```

If you still get a space, you can use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove it:

```
$url =  'http://alpha.com/zidd/id/' . trim($abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use: `preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $variable)` to remove whitespace from inside a string, and trim, for the start and end. This may help you out.
The `$variable` would be the your `$url`.

Comment: bit overkill when there are built in functions to handle trimming or str_replacing

Comment: I agree, but it's simple to use for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want the following:

```
$abc='akr:/9888/fk4f76mhn';
```

Comment: Argh! The semicolon! Thanks Jason.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$url =  'http://alpha.com/zidd/id/'.trim($abc);
```